# Getting a busy signal when calling a client device

Tags: twilio

I've using the basic phone example from Twilio, have set it up to use the auth.php example and have directed a purchased phone number to basic-call.php.

When I try to call that number, I hear the default prompt, but then get a busy signal and nothing happens in the app. Both the auth.php and the basic-call.php are set to use the same client ID (basic), and I can't find any documentation on Twilio about what it means if there's a busy signal when directing to a client app.

I don't have any PHP errors in the logs or any errors showing up in the Twilio console, if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I wasn't signing the request with the account SID and auth token of the subaccount that number was associated with. I sure hope this helps someone else!